# Is $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \mathbb{N}\}$, $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \}$ or $ \{ \emptyset \}$ an inductive family?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, induction

I know what is an inductive set. I know that $\mathbb{N}$ is an inductive set and I know that $\emptyset$ is an inductive set. But what is an inductive family? Is $\mathbb{N}$ an inductive family?

What about $\mathbb{N} \cup \{ \mathbb{N}\}$, $\{n \in \mathbb{N}: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \}$ or $\{ \emptyset  \}$?

Comment: In what context did you encounter the term "inductive family"?

Comment: In my math book, in the chapter on numbers. It was written that $\mathbb{N}$ is an inductive set and that is the smallest of them. In the questions at the end of chapter to "check your knowledge" they are asking if "families (mentioned in my question) are inductive".

Comment: I would guess "inductive family" is the same meaning as "inductive set".

Comment: "Family" is (usually and unless stated otherwise) the same as "set", but we often tend to think as elements of a family as "sets" themselves (for example, $\mathbb N$ would not be called a family, because we don't really tink of its elements as "sets", even if they are actually sets in ZF(C); on the contrary, I guess that $\mathcal P (\mathbb N))$ could be called a family, and that would not sound too strange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (usual) definition of inductive set is:

> We call a set, $A$, an *inductive set* when $∅∈A$ and whenever $x∈A$ then $Sx=x∪\{x\}∈A$

So $∅$ is **not** an inductive set.

Note that if there exists $B$ such that $SB=A$ then $A$ is **not** inductive:

If $A=SB$ then $B∈A$ but $SB=A∉A$

So, $Sℕ=ℕ∪\{ℕ\}$ and $S∅=∅∪\{∅\}=\{∅\}$ are both not inductive.

$\{n \in \mathbb{N}: 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} \}$ is just $ℕ$, so it is inductive.

Comment: So $\emptyset $ is not itself an inductive set / family, but If $\mathcal{A}$ is an inductive set / family then $\emptyset  \in \mathcal{A}$? And $\{ \emptyset \}$ itself is not an inductive set / family either. Am I right?

Comment: @mathmath yeah, you are correct

Comment: Also for every inductive set / family called $ \mathcal{A} $, $\mathbb{N} \subseteq \mathcal{A}$. Am I right?

Comment: @mathmath by definition, yes(it is exactly the intersection of all inductive sets)

Comment: great, thank you